# Git Token Authentication Failing

Tags: git, github

I'm setting up git repository in my new laptop, and I was able to clone my repo successfully. However, when I'm trying to push after making changes, it asks me to login via token, and I entered a fresh newly created token. Still, I'm getting `fatal: A task was canceled.` error message.

I've tried `git remote -v` and that is pointed to right repo.

Not sure what's going on

Comment: What permissions did you grant the token?

Comment: @JimRedmond Every checklist under "Repository permissions" and none under "User permissions"